# Is it possible to have AWS EBS persistent volumes on an on-prem K8s cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I wanted to use some AWS EBS volumes as a persistent storage for a deployment. I've configured the storage class and a PV, but I haven't been able to configure a Cloud provider.

The K8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) (as far as I understand) is for Kubernetes clusters running on a specific cloud provider, instead of an on-prem cluster using cloud resources. As the title says: Is it possible to have AWS EBS persistent volumes on an on-prem K8s cluster?

If so, can you a cloud provider to your existing cluster? (everything I've found online suggests that you add it when running kubeadm init).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use EBS storage in the same manner as you would when running on the cloud but you can use [AWS Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/features/) to store snapshots/backups of your volumes in cloud.

> AWS Storage Gateway is a hybrid cloud storage service that connects
>   your existing on-premises environments with the AWS Cloud

The feature you are intrested in is called **Volume Gateway**

> The Volume Gateway presents your applications block storage volumes
>   using the iSCSI protocol. Data written to these volumes can be
>   asynchronously backed up as point-in-time snapshots of your volumes,
>   and stored in the cloud as Amazon EBS snapshots.

Unfortunately you might not be able to automate creation of volumes in a way you could when running directly on AWS so some things you might have to do manually.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot because EBS can only be mounted inside AWS (usually in EC2 instances).